# TextInputHost.exe crashing and using a lot of CPU

Tags: windows

Like 2 or 1 days ago I started to have this problem where the process `TextInputHost.exe` just starts the error reporting tool process `WerFault.exe` as its child process and does something.

After 1 the second the whole process tree terminates itself and starts `TextInputHost.exe` again along with the `WerFault.exe` process 0.5 seconds later and this just keeps happening over and over again.

The `WerFault.exe` process uses `6-9%` of my CPU
and when the `TextInputHost.exe` gets terminated and starts up again, the new process will use over `23%` of my CPU for 0,5 seconds.

Picture of the TextInputHost.exe process:
[image: Picture of the TextInputHost.exe process]

After taking a look to the even viewer I found some errors from this category: "Windows-logs\Application"

This is what I found:
[image: Error log]

From this point on I don't know how I could fix this, It seems like Edge has something to do with this but I am not sure.

But here's the link to download the event viewer log file: (Since I cant just paste it here)
https://www.mediafire.com/file/i7evuw06yhex6sx

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Also run a deep anti-virus scan.

Comment: I think I started to have this problem after I uninstalled this software called RollbackRx.

https://horizondatasys.com/rollback-rx-time-machine/rollback-rx-professional/

It is an alternative to Windows restore points, it will start before the Windows OS and manage backups from a very low firmware level. After I uninstalled it I think it messed up something?

Comment: Everything is possible. What did the above tests say?

Comment: I watched some tutorials on YouTube and I fixed this a while ago. I remember that I just had to modify some files to fix this issue. But recently the issue came back and I didn't remember how to fix it, but a few days ago the issue just disappeared somehow, I didn't do anything ‍♂️

Comment: This issue keeps coming back every time I update my Windows version, and it goes away after some time using the updated version of Windows, i am not sure if I do something on my system after an update that gets rid of the issue, but it has gone away after a few days after updating Windows